# Multiple colors per line subroutine creating an error

Tags: batch-file

I wanted a simple program to display a value in red or green to show it's status. I have done this before in other programs. This time however it is being odd and doing this:

[image: problem]

I have no clue why it is giving me the "FINDSTR" errors. My code in it's entirety is here for your checking: http://pastebin.com/UpXCrWeW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the filename colorize function of `findstr`. But, a file name can not include a `:` (among other characters) it its name, so your code fails when a string with a colon is used.

User carlos at dostips.com has developped a more tolerant version of this code. [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32630#p32630) you can find the updated code

Comment: Ah I see. I'll just use a - instead of a : inside the "s then.